# Odd or Even symplectic structure in BV formalism

Tags: differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, supersymmetry, poisson-brackets, superalgebra

I am studying Batalin-Vilkovisky formalism. I am a little bit confused on what an odd (or even) symplectic structure is (i know what the degree of the underlying 2-form is). I can not find a clear definition anywhere. I read that an even bilinear form $B$ is even if $B(x,x)=0$ for all $x$ and odd if it exists $x$ such that $B(x,x)=1$ but this does not seem to me to be the right definition for a symplectic form. Could someone enlighten me on this point?

Comment: What source do you use? Textbook or review article.

Comment: @DanielC i use both

Comment: Hi Far. Welcome to Phys.SE. Which references? Which pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. An even (odd) [symplectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) 2-form
   $\omega~=~\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{d}z^I ~\omega_{IJ}(z)~ \mathrm{d}z^J  $ on a [supermanifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermanifold) means a Grassmann-even (Grassmann-odd) closed non-degenerate 2-form, respectively.
2. There is a straightforward generalization to even and odd [Poisson structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_manifold) on [supermanifolds](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/supermanifold).
3. The Hamiltonian Batalin-Fradkin-Vilkovisky (BFV) formalism uses an even Poisson bracket, while the Lagrangian [Batalin-Vilkovisky (BV) formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalin%E2%80%93Vilkovisky_formalism) uses an odd Poisson bracket (also known as an antibracket).